# Spring Multipart File with @RequestBody

Tags: spring, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload data from an app to a spring backend service.
Things to upload are a DataModel containing data of the object to create and several images linked to the data.
Therefore I am using this method signature:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Survey createSurvey(@RequestBody SurveyPostHelper helper, @RequestParam(value="file", required = true) MultipartFile[] images)
```

I tried to play with the annotations, but either I get a blank images array or my helper is empty.
How would you solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you provide a code which is used for uploading images?

Comment: I do this with Alamofire, but I solved it in the mean while. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out, that this method signature could do the job:

```
@ResponseBody
public Survey createSurvey(@RequestPart(required=true) SurveyPostHelper helper, @RequestPart(value="file", required = true) final MultipartFile[] images)
```

Important in my case was to set the MimeType in the client app. The files MimeType should be `image/jpg` and the `SurveyPostHelper`s to `application/json` to allow Spring to parse the json and bind it to my Object.

Comment: could you please show your client app? are you sending it with ajax?

Comment: I am sending from an iOS application with the Alamofire lib. It uses a multipart POST request to upload multipe images and a JSON object. This should be possible via AJAX, too.

Answer (score 3):

see an example of the client code working for me images is the list of files I want to save

var formData = new FormData();

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length ; i++) {
  formData.append('images', images[i]);
}

formData.append('adData', new Blob([JSON.stringify(adData)], {
    type: "application/json"
}));
```